# How to undo an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create an effect where if I hover over a certain element a paragraph element will be gradually displayed and vice versa (If the cursor is no longer hovering on the element the paragraph  should gradually fade). I've already created the effect using pure CSS, but it was a bit cumbersome and it will only work if the paragraph is a direct child of the element I'm hovering on (which made it even more cumbersome). But here's how I created using CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.FlexContainerRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.FlixItem_Images {
  width: 50rem;
}

#CheiftianTwo {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color color linear;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: 13.75em;
  margin-top: 6.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}

#divForLayers {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#divForhover {
  height: 33.5em;
  width: 100rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

#divForhover:hover #welcome {
  transition: background-color color linear;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="divForhover">
    <div id="divForLayers">
      <div id="HeaderImagesContainer" class="FlexContainerRow">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.nexusindustrialmemory.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/OriginalTank.jpg" class="FlixItem_Images" id="CheiftianOne" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.nexusindustrialmemory.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/OriginalTank.jpg" class="FlixItem_Images" id="CheiftianTwo" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="welcome">Welcome to te Cheftian Mk.2 Main Battle Tank guide!</p>
  </div>
</header>
<nav></nav>
<footer></footer>
```

But I've just learned that you can do the same thing with JavaScript and it will be much much simpler:

```js
addEventListner('mouseover', function(evt) {
  document.body.querySelector( /*ID_of_the_element*/ ).style.property = 'value';
})
```

The problem is that I only know how to to display the paragraph when the user hovers on the element, and that's it. If the cursor is no longer on the element, the paragraph will still be displayed. I don't know how to **undo** the `addEventListener`. I tried to do it with `removeEventListener`, but apparently I have the syntax wrong. Please tell me how to do it.

Here's the version with the JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("#welcome").style.visibility = "hidden";

var imgOne = document.body.querySelector("#CheiftianOne");

imgOne.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
  var textBox = document.querySelector("#welcome");
  textBox.style.visibility = "visible";
});

imgOne.removeEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
  var textBox = document.querySelector("#welcome");
  textBox.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.FlexContainerRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.FlixItem_Images {
  width: 50rem;
}

#CheiftianTwo {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color color linear;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 13.75em;
  margin-top: 6.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
}

#divForLayers {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="divForhover">
    <div id="divForLayers">
      <div id="HeaderImagesContainer" class="FlexContainerRow">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.nexusindustrialmemory.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/OriginalTank.jpg" class="FlixItem_Images" id="CheiftianOne" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.nexusindustrialmemory.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/OriginalTank.jpg" class="FlixItem_Images" id="CheiftianTwo" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="welcome">Welcome to te Cheftian Mk.2 Main Battle Tank guide!</p>
  </div>
</header>
<nav></nav>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the event handler function to a variable, or give it a proper name. Then add and remove *that*.

Your `removeEventListener` call is failing because you're passing it a *unique* function.

Also, you actually don't want to *undo* the event listener to achieve the effect you want. Instead, listen to separate events: `mouseover` and `mouseout`. For example:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var par = document.getElementById('par');

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  par.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
  par.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Hover over me</button>

<p id="par" style="visibility: hidden;">This shows when hovering over the button</p>
```

The `mouseover` event occurs when the mouse hovers over an element, and conversely the `mouseout` event occurs when the mouse leaves the element.

Comment: *"Also, you actually don't want to undo the event listener to achieve the effect you want..."* Nice one, going beyond the obvious to read the code closely enough to address the real problem! :-)

Comment: Thanks mate! adding 2 (addEventListener)'s instead of an addEventListener and a removeEventListeners worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

When you call `removeEventListener`, you have to pass it the **same** function you passed `addEventListener`, not a different-but-equivalent one. This will never remove a listener:

```
imgOne.removeEventListener('mouseover', function (evt) { /* ... */ });
```

...because by definition, that exact function wasn't ever added previously.

Remember the one you used when adding, and use that same one when removing.

Separately: Adding the handler and then *immediately* removing it doesn't make a lot of sense. Nothing can happen that will trigger the handler between the calls to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` in your code. (Edit: Ah, [rossipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115049/rossipedia) has picked up on why you did that, and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003066/157247) tells you want to do instead.)

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. I used a function with the same name across the addEventListener and the removeEventListener and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I figured out how to do it without a removeEventListener. (I used two addEventListener).

Thanks, again!